# Unable to add child elements using xmlgen

Tags: xml, haskell

I'm experimenting using the xmlgen library to generate some relatively simple xmd documents; however, I'm finding the syntax difficult to get working.

This simple example works:

```
people = [("Stefan", "32"), ("Judith", "4")]

genXml''' :: [(String, String)] -> Xml Doc
genXml''' people = 
   doc defaultDocInfo $ 
        xelem "SERVICES" $ xattr "transaction" "SHARE" 

outputXml :: IO ()
outputXml = BSL.putStrLn (xrender $ genXml''' people)
```

But when I try to add a child element like this:

```
genXml''' :: [(String, String)] -> Xml Doc
genXml''' people = 
    doc defaultDocInfo $ 
        xelem "SERVICES" $ xattr "transaction" "SHARE" $
            xelem "SERVICE"
```

I get the following compile errors:

> Couldn't match type `Xml' with`(->) (c0 -> Xml Elem)'
>       The function `xattr' is applied to two arguments, but its type`[Char] -> Text.XML.Generator.MkAttrRes [Char] [Char]' has only one
>       In the expression: xattr "transaction" "SHARE"
>       In the second argument of `($)', namely`
>
>   xattr "transaction" "SHARE" $ xelem "SERVICE"'

I've tried putting `<>` or `<#>` at the end of the `xelem "SERVICES" $ xattr "transaction" "SHARE" $` line, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the docs of xmlgen,

```
genXml''' :: [(String, String)] -> Xml Doc
genXml''' people = 
    doc defaultDocInfo $
        xelem "SERVICES" (xattr "transaction" "SHARE" <#> xelemEmpty "SERVICE")
```

ought to work.

Your code tries to add "SERVICE" to the "transaction" attribute, which does not work.